# BeagleBone Black IOError: [Errno 16] Device or resource busy when using I2C to communicate with BNO055 sensor

Tags: debian, i2c, beagleboneblack, device-tree, adafruit

i am trying to use the Adafruit_bno55 Library with a beaglebone black(debian 10 .3 buster) to attain data across the i2c bus from the BNO055 sensor. However when i try to run the test code that they offer here:

(https://learn.adafruit.com/bno055-absolute-orientation-sensor-with-raspberry-pi-and-beaglebone-black/software)

I receive an error message which will be displayed below.

When i type the following code that's supposed to read data from the BNO055 sensor on the i2c bus i get the following error:

```
root@beaglebone:~/Adafruit_Python_BNO055/examples# sudo python simpletest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "simpletest.py", line 45, in <module>
    if not bno.begin():
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/Adafruit_BNO055/BNO055.py", line 382, in begin
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/Adafruit_BNO055/BNO055.py", line 358, in _config_mode
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/Adafruit_BNO055/BNO055.py", line 416, in set_mode
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/Adafruit_BNO055/BNO055.py", line 302, in _write_byte
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/Adafruit_GPIO/I2C.py", line 116, in write8
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/Adafruit_PureIO/smbus.py", line 322, in write_byte_data
IOError: [Errno 16] Device or resource busy
```

**EDIT**

I suspect that there might be some issue with the device tree overlays but i am unsure. I found out that i was viewing the incorrect i2c bus and that was why the device was not showing up orginally. When i look at i2c bus #2 the device pops up with its default address of 0x28.

```
debian@beaglebone:/var/lib/cloud9$ i2cdetect -y -r 2
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 28 -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

Although the sensor address is showing the error still persists.

I will appreciate any help in resolving this issue. Thank you.

Comment: Do you know what devices are at 0x24, 0x34, 0x50 and 0x70?

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/8/i2cdetect @0andriy This link states that "UU" means that probing was skipped, because this address is currently in use by a driver.  As for address 34, i am not sure which device this is.

Comment: I know what it means, my question was about something else.